# Tree Traversal in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Here is a peice of code to traverse a tree which is not working:

```
data Tree = Leaf Int | Node Int Tree Tree deriving Show 

preorder(Leaf n) = [n]
preorder(Node n t0 t1) = [n] ++ (preorder t0) ++ (preorder t1)

inorder(Leaf n) = [n]
inorder(Node n t0 t1) = (inorder t0) ++ [n] ++ (inorder t1)

postorder(Leaf n) = [n]
postorder(Node n t0 t1) = (postorder t0) ++ (postorder t1) ++ [n]
```

I have been asked to execute the following:

```
Node 8 (Node 3 (Leaf 5) (Leaf 2)) (Node 1 (Leaf 9) (Leaf 6))
```

When I execute the above statement it returns back as it is, when it should return:

```
preorder t = [8,3,5,2,1,9,6]

inorder t = [5,3,2,8,9,1,6]

postorder t =[5,2,3,9,6,1,8]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem; `postorder (Node 8 (Node 3 (Leaf 5) (Leaf 2)) (Node 1 (Leaf 9) (Leaf 6)))` gives the expected result, as does applying `inorder` and `postorder` to that same tree.

Comment: Asked by whom? Is this a homework?

Comment: if `t = Node 8 (Node 3 (Leaf 5) (Leaf 2)) (Node 1 (Leaf 9) (Leaf 6))`, this works as expected.

Comment: Oh! You're literally evaluating `Node 8 (Node 3 (Leaf 5) (Leaf 2)) (Node 1 (Leaf 9) (Leaf 6))`, and getting the same result back. That's data, and you need to give it to a function, to return a new value.

Comment: Yes, as @amindfv writes, fire up ghci and just type in `preorder (Node 8 (Node 3 (Leaf 5) (Leaf 2)) (Node 1 (Leaf 9) (Leaf 6)))` (and hit ender). This will evaluate the function `preorder` on this tree.

Answer (score 5):

What you have given:

```
Node 8 (Node 3 (Leaf 5) (Leaf 2)) (Node 1 (Leaf 9) (Leaf 6))
```

is a **value** of type `Tree`.  You can give this value a name by creating a **binding** or **definition** for it.  If you're working in a source file, you can just do

```
myTree = Node 8 (Node 3 (Leaf 5) (Leaf 2)) (Node 1 (Leaf 9) (Leaf 6))
```

or give it a **type signature**:

```
myTree :: Tree  -- this is the type signature
myTree = Node 8 (Node 3 (Leaf 5) (Leaf 2)) (Node 1 (Leaf 9) (Leaf 6))
```

If you're working in the interpreter, **`ghci`**, you can use **`let`** to create a new definition:

```
Prelude> let myTree = Node 8 (Node 3 (Leaf 5) (Leaf 2)) (Node 1 (Leaf 9) (Leaf 6))
```

Your task seems to be to evaluate each of the functions `postorder`, `inorder` and `preorder` when given this tree.  If you're in a source file, you'll want to save the result in a definition:

```
inOrderResult :: [Int]
inOrderResult = inorder myTree
```

(Note that we passed in `myTree` as an **argument** to the **function** `inorder`.) And if you're working with `ghci`, just typing

```
Prelude> inorder myTree
```

will print the result to the terminal.